# Skipping resource provider: Blockchain not supported by this resource provider

Tags: wallet

I'm using Anchor Wallet to sign my transactions (through UAL) and sometimes, it's bugging with this error whenever I try to sign a transaction:

`Skipping resource provider: Blockchain not supported by this resource provider.`

Logging in and out fixes it though.

Answer (score 2):

This actually is an unrelated message, and a "notice" put into the console for developers to know what's happening internally during the transaction signing process.

If transactions are not reaching Anchor through UAL, it's very likely it's related to a connection issue we've been battling for a while now with Anchor, where it loses connection to the messaging services used to relay encrypted messages back and forth between the wallet and dApp using UAL.

Restarting Anchor or logging out and back in typically reconnects things, which is why it started working again.